# Firebase functions incorrect statusCode error

Tags: firebase, paypal, google-cloud-functions

Hi I'm trying to use firebase functions to cancel my apps paypal subscription, this code works since when i check the paypal subscription from paypal api they are canceled. But the problem is that the firebase functions always return "Error: could not handle the request" and in logs it shows error below message. How can i change my code so it dosen't return this error and forwards the response from paypal api to my app or atleast return 200 code if paypal api returns 204 or 422?

```
Error: Incorrect statusCode: 422
    at ClientRequest.h.request (/srv/node_modules/bent/src/nodejs.js:132:23)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:315:30)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient (_http_client.js:552:21)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:119:17)
    at TLSSocket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:454:20)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:263:12)
```

My code

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
const bent = require('bent');

admin.initializeApp();

exports.cancelPaypalSubscription = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  const id = req.query.id;
  const post = bent(
    'https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/billing/subscriptions/' + id,
    'POST',
    {'Authorization': 'Basic ' + functions.config().paypal.key,
     'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    });
  return await post('/cancel', {reason: "User account deleted"});
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like there is an unhandled exception when you call `post()` method. Try to wrap it in try/catch:

```
try {
  await post('/cancel', {reason: "User account deleted"});
} catch (err) {
  // handle error
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The PayPal API returns a `422` HTTP status code, which means that the request you're making is not correct according to the API.

From quickly scanning the API documentation on the [subscription API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/subscriptions/integrate/#3-create-a-plan), it seems that you can't `POST` to a specific subscription URL. To cancel a subscription you need to post to `https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/billing/subscriptions/I-EXCCE2B4J0D5/cancel`, so with `/cancel` added to the end.

Comment: my problem isn't with what the paypal api returns the problem I'm trying to solve is that firebase functions returns "Error: could not handle the request" instead of just forwarding the response that paypal api returned